# Executing code if three conditions are false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to skip over calculating some numbers when the result would be an attempt to insert NaN into the DB.  My code is as follows:

```
unless @X = 0 || @Y = 0 || Z= 0 #Don't execute below code if any of the three values = 0
    #Do some stuff with @X, @Y and @Z
end
```

I know that X,Y and Z are positive integers, as they should be, however this statement is not triggering the code block in the unless clause.  Am I blatantly misusing the || operator?

Comment: the `=` is an assignment operator, what you want is an equality operator: `==`

Comment: derp. That does it, thanks for responding to such a moronic question. Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `=` the assignment operator. You want to be using `==` the equality operator. Your code should look like this:

```
unless @X == 0 || @Y == 0 || @Z == 0
...
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be using a double equals (`==`) for comparison in an `if` or `unless` clause, not a single equals (`=`).

Answer (score 0):

Especially when you want to compare with zero, there is a built in command in ruby which is faster than doing `== 0`.

```
unless @x.zero? or @y.zero? or @z.zero?
  ...
end
```

You can use either `||` or `or` here.